# NgIf data is loading but showing no data at first

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a page that loads the current activity of the user. If the user leaves that activity, it shows a different template with no activity.

**current-activity.page.html**

```
<div *ngIf="activities;then temp_activities; else temp_no_activities"></div>
    <ng-template #temp_activities>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #temp_no_activities>
    </ng-template>
```

**current-activity.page.ts**

```
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    return this.activitiesService.getCurrentActivityDetails().subscribe(data => {
      this.activities = data;
    }),
    (err) => {
      console.log (err)
    };
  }
```

The data loads correctly, but in the first second I load the page it shows the #temp_no_activities, which it shouldn't, because there is data. After that it shows #temp_activities correctly. Any ideas about this?

Comment: If you're fetching activities from what I assume is an API call, the `activities` variable will remain null till it is populated with the data returned from the call. The brief moment before the `activities` variable is populated is what you see when you reload the page and get to view the #temp_no_activities

Comment: Thank you, that's what I assumed. What would be the best thing to do in this case?

Comment: If you do not want the #temp_no_activities showing up when 'activities' are being fetched, you could introduce a 'loading' variable. That way you can change the condition to not show anything if `loading === true`. And you can set `loading` to false once `activities` are fetched

Comment: Thank you man, you've been really helpful!